# Bucles con y sin llaves en C

Tags: c, bucle-for

estaba haciendo un programa recientemente, donde ocupaba sacar un promedio de una n cantidades, para lo que usé el bucle for.
Y me percaté que se ejecuta de diferente manera dependiendo de si le colocas o no llaves.
Pongo código abajo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    float prom1 = 0, prom2 = 0;
    
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        prom1 = prom1 + i;
        prom1 = prom1 / 3;
    }


    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        prom2 = prom2 + i;
        prom2 = prom2 / 3;

    
    printf("El prom1 es %f\n", prom1);  // Imprime un 0.77...
    printf("El prom2 es %f", prom2);   // Imprime un 1

  return 0;
}
```

Alguien me podría explicar exactamente porqué en el for que tiene llaves ejecuta las sentencias en orden de arriba a abajo y luego regresa de nuevo arriba.

Y en el que no las tiene primero ejecuta la primera sentencia iterando a i hasta que la condición se deja de cumplir y entonces pasa a la segunda.

También me interesa saber si hay un límite de sentencias para el que no tiene llaves.

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C, muchas instrucciones se deben acompañar de una serie de instrucciones entre llaves. (`if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, `switch`, funciones, etc).

Sucede que en algunas de ellas, cuando el bloque contiene una sola instrucción, se permite omitir las llaves.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un código como:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    j++;
}
```

Puedes escribirlo así:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    j++;
```

Cómo has podido notar:

> Y en el que no las tiene primero ejecuta la primera sentencia iterando a i hasta que la condición se deja de cumplir y entonces pasa a la segunda.

Las líneas:

```
for(i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    prom2 = prom2 + i;
    prom2 = prom2 / 3;
```

Se compilan como si se tratase de:

```
for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    prom2 = prom2 + i;
}
prom2 = prom2 / 3;
```

No debes olvidar que en C la identación no importa.

---

> También me interesa saber si hay un límite de sentencias para el que no tiene llaves.

Solo una por bloque. Aunque podría parecer contradictorio, podrías reescribir algo como esto:

```
if (true){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (i == 5){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

De este modo:

```
if (true)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (i == 5)
            break;
```

Es válido, porque en cada bloque hay una sola instrucción. Cuando se trata de ciclos o condicionales, la instrucción con su bloque cuentan como uno solo.

Como posiblemente estés notando, cuesta más entender el último código que su versión con llaves. Así que intenta no anidar muchas instrucciones si quieres hacer tu código mantenible.